# Update and Select in same ADO.NET ExecuteReader call

Tags: vb.net, t-sql, transactions, ado.net

I'm working with someone else's code I inherited and I need a sanity check.

It seems in the SQL below that the update statements don't get run, only the select statement. I'm wondering if it has anything to do with the transaction? I have similar code I've written elsewhere that works just fine. And this same pattern is repeated throughout the inherited code so none of it should work, but it seemingly was working before.

The purpose of this code is to bring in data from a flat file source, clean it up, and eventually bring it into a table with proper data types for reporting. To do the cleanup it puts it in a temp table with all varchar columns.

Anyway, why won't these update statements have any effect?

```
Dim oConn As New SqlConnection(ProgConnString)
Dim oTrans As SqlTransaction
oConn.Open()
oTrans = oConn.BeginTransaction()

'Create the temp staging table
Dim strTempTableName As String = CreateTempTable(oConn, oTrans, oDataTable)

'Write the passed DataTable to the temp staging table
Dim copier As New SqlBulkCopy(oConn, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, oTrans)
copier.DestinationTableName = strTempTableName
copier.BulkCopyTimeout = 30
copier.WriteToServer(oDataTable)
copier.Close()

'This is the update statement that does not run
Dim strSQL As String = String.Empty
strSQL &= " UPDATE " & strTempTableName
strSQL &= " set [MyCol] = REPLACE([MyCol], '$', '') "
strSQL &= ", [MyCol2] = REPLACE([MyCol2], '$', '') "
strSQL &= ", [MyCol3] = REPLACE([MyCol3], '$', '') "

'[ some other update statements that also do not run... ]

' If I throw this in the mix, the update commands run
'Using oCmd1 As New SqlCommand(strSQL, oConn, oTrans)
'    oCmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
'End Using
'strSQL = ""

'This is where we pull back the result. It should have all the above
' fixes from the update statements but it doesn't
strSQL &= " SELECT * FROM " & strTempTableName

Dim oCmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL, oConn, oTrans)
Dim oDataReader As SqlDataReader = oCmd.ExecuteReader
Dim resultDataTable As New DataTable
resultDataTable.Load(oDataReader)

'Drop temp table
strSQL = ""
strSQL &= vbNewLine & "IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.." & strTempTableName & "') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE " & strTempTableName
oCmd = New SqlCommand()
oCmd.Connection = oConn
oCmd.Transaction = oTrans
oCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
oCmd.CommandText = strSQL
oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

oTrans.Commit()

'Use the results
SomeFunctionWhatever(resultDataTable)
```

Now what does work is if I split it up with an `ExecuteNonQuery()` before the select.

What's causing the `Update` commands to be ignored, is it the transaction? You can do an `Update` and `Select` within the same `ExecuteReader()` call, right?

Comment: Is the transaction ever committed?  If so, you didn't show it.

Comment: Hmm, good point. I updated the code. Looks like the transaction gets committed after the select call. Probably shouldn't be in a transaction at all. But seeing as how the create temp table and bulk copy calls are also all in the transaction, why wouldn't the update calls work?

Comment: If you call `resultDataTable.Load(oDataReader)` multiple times in a row, does it ever get the results?  I wouldn't expect that command to generate multiple result sets, but if it did, `DataTable.Load` will only fill the table one result set at a time.  Alternatively, you could use a `DataSet` which would get them all at once.

Comment: There's only one dataset to load. And it loads regardless. The issue is the dataset never has any of the changes applied to it by the update queries.

Comment: could you try oTrans = oConn.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted) perhaps?

Comment: @StevenDoggart looks like your comment is the closest to an answer that we found. Could you elaborate in an answer on why having it in a transaction prevents the select from getting the changes from the updates that precede it? I'll be glad to make that the accepted answer.

Comment: Did you try playing with the isolation level, as @Ctznkane525 was suggesting?  That would be my first guess too.